# getItemValueArray with big Value List edit operation so slow

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-ssjs

multivalue fields editing from repeat control with this code. if value lists not big ok/fast but value list is big bring data slowly to dialog (bootstrap)

This button code in repeat control

```
<xp:button value="-" id="submitButtonId2" styleClass = "btn btn-success">                           
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="pnlRow" disableValidators="true" id="eventHandler3">
    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.index = rowIndex;
 EditRow();}]]></xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler>
        <xp:this.attrs> <xp:attr name="data-toggle" value="modal">
                                                </xp:attr>
                    <xp:attr name="data-target" value="#OrderRow">
                                                </xp:attr>
                                            </xp:this.attrs>
                                        </xp:button>
```

EditRow script lib function

```
var arRowDesc = document1.getItemValueArray("RowDesc")[index];
getComponent("RestipDesc").setValue(arRowDesc);

var arBrand = document1.getItemValueArray("Brand")[index];
getComponent("pickBrand").setValue(arBrand);

var arModel = document1.getItemValueArray("Model")[index];
getComponent("pickModel").setValue(arModel);

var arSupCode = document1.getItemValueArray("SupCode")[index];
getComponent("inSupCode").setValue(arSupCode);

var arQuantity = document1.getItemValueArray("Quantity")[index];
getComponent("RestipQuantity").setValue(arQuantity);

var arUnit = document1.getItemValueArray("Unit")[index];
getComponent("inUnit").setValue(arUnit);

var arListPrice = document1.getItemValueArray("ListPrice")[index];
getComponent("pickListPrice").setValue(arListPrice);

var arDisc = document1.getItemValueArray("Disc")[index];
getComponent("pickDisc").setValue(arDisc);

var arVat = document1.getItemValueArray("Vat")[index];
getComponent("pickVat").setValue(arVat);

var arOTVRows = document1.getItemValueArray("OTVRows")[index];
getComponent("pickOtv").setValue(arOTVRows);
```

Comment: what is "big"? and provide more code, maybe you kill it by iterating and data conversion (it seems you repeatedly call getItemValueArry INSIDE the loop - a big NO NO!)

Comment: Oh yeah, just what @FrantisekKossuth says. It would be better to copy the `getItemValueArray` contents into a `viewScope`'d var and only get the current `rowIndex` off of that. Would drastically reduce the number of calls back to the doc and populating of a temp var.

Comment: I assume you typed this in, and didn't copy and paste from your code, since you have a typo on the first line?

Comment: i repost my code (button, lib function). I have not loop for example these fields(RowDesc,  Brand etc..) have 4 line value no problem if 100 line value when click edit button slowly coming data to bootstrap dialog

Comment: use EL whenever possible. or at least try this call: getItemValue().get(index), if it helps

Comment: using getComponent.setValue() is always "expensive" - try using the backend document instead and do a (partial) refresh of your Xpage

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to avoid this pattern:

```
var value = document.getItemValueArray("field")[index];
getComponent("component").setValue(value);
```

Bind components to document by EL:

```
value="#{document1.field[index]}"
```

You need to redo your save button, I assume you pick updated values similarly and transfer them to document.

And show that component only if you want to, so your edit button will toggle visibility of your edit component.